# How to edit "Bank Transaction Fee" total title

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, template, localisation

I am trying to edit the name of "bank transaction fee" to "handling fee" but I cant find the word "bank transaction fee" in the template. Where can I edit this word?

This is the code for that but I dont know where is the path

```
<?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 3 : 2; ?>

<?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the totals are not directly written in a template, but generated from the quote. "Bank Transaction Fee" is a custom total, added by a payment extension.

It should be a translatable string, so to change the title, use translations (yes, you can create translations for any language, even `en_US`).

I would suggest using theme translations, as described under "project specific theme" in [What is the proper way to add theme-specific translations of new strings?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-theme-specific-translations-of-new-strings/83003#83003)

---

Alternatively you could use inline translations which are saved in the database:

#### Summarizing the [documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/design/interface-text-change.html?Highlight=inline%20translation):

> 1. **Add Your IP Address to the Developer Mode Whitelist** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 2. **Disable Output Caches** (System > Cache Management)
> 3. **Activate the Translate Inline Tool** (System > Configuration > Developer)
> 4. **Update the Text** (Click the [image: book] icon next to any text in the frontend that you want to change)
> 5. **Restore Original Settings**

Comment: Thank you, i able to change that text on the front end but when i checked the text on the Invoice Transaction Email notification, it is still "Bank Transaction Fee". How to change the title inside the template email notification?