# Can I make a root language folder in app/locale like in zend?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I'm a newbie to magento and even zend. I've noticed that in zend `lib/Zend/locale/data` locales are defined as a base file like `en.xml` and more locale files like `en_uk`,`en_us`. 
can I do that in `app/locale`? what's the best approach in my case?

**My case is**:
I'm working on a multi-website magento 1.9 each site is related to a certain country all available in english, French, arabic. so the theme must be translated to those languages in all websites and I don't want to use one locale and don't want to rewrite all common strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a new locale for each country/language combination. Locales are not just languages, they also contain other localized information like how to format dates and currencies. You usually should not want/need to invent your own locales which are not defined in `lib/Zend`.

For example you can use `en_US` for all English store views, and `fr_FR` for all French store views.

If you want to change some translations per website, you can use a different child theme per website and change translations in `translate.csv` of the themes. Read more: [What is the proper way to add theme-specific translations of new strings?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-theme-specific-translations-of-new-strings/83003#83003)

Comment: thanks alot @fabian, actually I thought about locale as I wanted to make something like cultural translation considering date formats for example and really want to make it the magento way as the system was completely hard coded

Comment: I would try to choose an existing locale `xx_XX` that suits your desired date formats etc. and then copy the Magento language pack if necessary (e.g. `app/etc/locale/en_US` to `app/etc/locale/xx_XX`).

Comment: actually I've `app/etc/locale/eg_ar` with so many .csv files the question is should I make a copy for `app/etc/locale/uae_ar` and just edit the diff.s? in this case any change shall be done on all locales. no way else?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. In the core there is no inheritance mechanism for locales. BUT there is an open source extension that will help you: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_LocaleFallback